# Cannot find the symmetric key 'e1', because it does not exist or you do not have permission. (SQL Server 2019)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019, encryption

It seems to be a weird error, I have tried everything from giving Control, Alter, and View Definition permission on the symmetric key but nothing seems to work out.

Tried everything from this article.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-symmetric-key-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

**It works perfectly fine when I grant sysadmin permission to the user, however not working with db_owner and db_datareader roles. A user with sysadmin privilege can access it without any issues.**

Have tried running the following alter command on the DB as well but still no go.

alter master key add encryption by service master key

Comment: You'll have to go through the users permissions, roles, etc., and see what is denying them access. When someone is given sysadmin, permissions checks are ignored which is why it works.